# how to make two buttons work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, button

I am trying to learn javascript and I am making a simple Fahrenheit Celsius application. The problem that I currently have is only one of two buttons work. in case there are 2 if statements , only button Fahrenheit2Celcius button works, in case there is an if... else if statement then only button Celcius2Fahrenheit works, but they never work both. Would you please explain what I am doing wrong? Here is my code:

```js
function C2F() {  
    var Stoinost = document.getElementById('Stoinost').value;
    var Fahrenheit = (Stoinost * 1.8) + 32;
    var fahrenheit2 = Math.round(Fahrenheit*100)/100;
    var C2F_but = document.getElementById("C2F");

    var Celcius = (Stoinost - 32) * (5/9);
    var Celcius2 = Math.round(Celcius*100)/100;
    var F2C_but = document.getElementById("F2C");


      if (C2F_but){
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = fahrenheit2;
      }

      if (F2C_but){
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = Celcius2;
      }

}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <tr><td><p> Input Value: <input type="number" id="Stoinost" size="20" ></p></td></tr>
    <td>
      <button onclick="C2F()" id="F2C">Fahrenheit2Celcius</button>
      <button onclick="C2F()" id="C2F">Celcius2Fahrenheit</button>
    </td>

    <tr><td><p> <div id="result">Result is displayed here.</div> </p></td></tr>  
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You are over writing `results`. Instead, set a parameter in your function to know which button was press

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem you are having is that C2F_but is a reference to the DOMNode, which is always truthy. So both conditionals will always evaluate to `true`. To do what you are wanting to do you need to get the `Event` object that is being submitted by the click event and then check to see which of those two DOMNodes was the triggering element.

```js
function C2F(event) {  
        var Stoinost = document.getElementById('Stoinost').value;
        var Fahrenheit = (Stoinost * 1.8) + 32;
        var fahrenheit2 = Math.round(Fahrenheit*100)/100;
        var C2F_but = document.getElementById("C2F");

        var Celcius = (Stoinost - 32) * (5/9);
        var Celcius2 = Math.round(Celcius*100)/100;
        var F2C_but = document.getElementById("F2C");


            if (event.target == C2F_but){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = fahrenheit2;
            }

            if (event.target == F2C_but){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = Celcius2;
            }

}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">

    <tr>
        <td><p> Input Value: <input type="number" id="Stoinost" size="20" ></p></td>
            <td>
                <button onclick="C2F(event)" id="F2C">Fahrenheit2Celcius</button>
                <button onclick="C2F(event)" id="C2F">Celcius2Fahrenheit</button>
            </td>
</tr>
        <tr><td><p> <div id="result">Result is displayed here.</div> </p></td></tr>     
    
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` when calling a function in an onclick handler and detect which element is clicked by checking for attributes on it like the id:

```js
function C2F(btn) {
  console.log(btn.id);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="C2F(this)" id="F2C">Fahrenheit2Celcius</button>
<button onclick="C2F(this)" id="C2F">Celcius2Fahrenheit</button>
```

But a much simpler and possible better solution would be to just use two functions.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong condition in your if statement. When you check if (c2f_but), it will always return true, because the button exists. You're not actually asking something about it.

What you want to know is if the button clicked is c2f_button. In that case, you would have to pass the click event as a parameter, and check if its target matches the button, or at least check some property of that button.

However, I don't think you need that kind of checking in this case. You can simply pass the calculation you want to make as a parameter of your function, like in the example below:

```js
function C2F(option) {  
        var Stoinost = document.getElementById('Stoinost').value;
        var Fahrenheit = (Stoinost * 1.8) + 32;
        var fahrenheit2 = Math.round(Fahrenheit*100)/100;
        /*var C2F_but = document.getElementById("C2F");*/

        var Celcius = (Stoinost - 32) * (5/9);
        var Celcius2 = Math.round(Celcius*100)/100;
        /*var F2C_but = document.getElementById("F2C");*/


            if (option == 'c2f'){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = fahrenheit2;
            }

            if (option == 'f2c'){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = Celcius2;
            }

}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">

    <tr>
        <tr><td><p> Input Value: <input type="number" id="Stoinost" size="20" ></p></td></tr>
            <td>
                <button onclick="C2F('f2c')" id="F2C">Fahrenheit2Celcius</button>
                <button onclick="C2F('c2f')" id="C2F">Celcius2Fahrenheit</button>
            </td>

        <tr><td><p> <div id="result">Result is displayed here.</div> </p></td></tr>     
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make two functions for different functionalities?

```js
function C2F() {  
    var Stoinost = document.getElementById('Stoinost').value;
    var Fahrenheit = (Stoinost * 1.8) + 32;
    var fahrenheit2 = Math.round(Fahrenheit*100)/100;

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = fahrenheit2;
}

function F2C() {  
    var Stoinost = document.getElementById('Stoinost').value;
    var Celcius = (Stoinost - 32) * (5/9);
    var Celcius2 = Math.round(Celcius*100)/100;

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = Celcius2;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <tr><td><p> Input Value: <input type="number" id="Stoinost" size="20" ></p></td></tr>
    <td>
      <button onclick="F2C()" id="F2C">Fahrenheit2Celcius</button>
      <button onclick="C2F()" id="C2F">Celcius2Fahrenheit</button>
    </td>

    <tr><td><p> <div id="result">Result is displayed here.</div> </p></td></tr>  
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would also suggest you to check your HTML, you have a `<tr>` directly inside another `<tr>`. It should be only `<td>`'s inside `<tr>`'s.

Answer (score 0):

You are over writing results. Instead, set a parameter in your function to know which button was press

```js
function C2F(type) {  
        var Stoinost = document.getElementById('Stoinost').value;
        var Fahrenheit = (Stoinost * 1.8) + 32;
        var fahrenheit2 = Math.round(Fahrenheit*100)/100;
        var C2F_but = document.getElementById("C2F");

        var Celcius = (Stoinost - 32) * (5/9);
        var Celcius2 = Math.round(Celcius*100)/100;
        var F2C_but = document.getElementById("F2C");


            if (type == 'cf'){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = fahrenheit2;
            }else{
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = Celcius2;
            }

}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">

    <tr>
        <tr><td><p> Input Value: <input type="number" id="Stoinost" size="20" ></p></td></tr>
            <td>
                <button onclick="C2F('fc')" id="F2C">Fahrenheit2Celcius</button>
                <button onclick="C2F('cf')" id="C2F">Celcius2Fahrenheit</button>
            </td>

        <tr><td><p> <div id="result">Result is displayed here.</div> </p></td></tr>     
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the function the action (button) you want to perform.

In this case you can pass the action as a parameter when calling the function C2F

```
<button onclick="C2F('f2c');" id="F2C">Fahrenheit2Celcius</button>
<button onclick="C2F('c2f');" id="C2F">Celcius2Fahrenheit</button>
```

And catching that action in the function:

```
if (action == 'c2f'){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = fahrenheit2;
}

if (action == 'f2c'){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = Celcius2;
}
```

I've created a working example here:
[Demo](https://jsbin.com/nagifarete/1/edit?html,js,output)